# Uploading Files to DropBox via Python

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload files to dropbox via the file_upload dropbox API. My code was working flawlessly the last two weeks and randomly stopped working and I cannot find any clear indication why. I've read through countless forums and documentation and can't seem to find a clear way to debug this. Any help or recommendation would be greatly appreciated! Note that df and upload in the code below are dataframes.

```
def to_dropbox(dataframe, path, token):

    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(token)

    df_string = dataframe.to_csv(index=False)
    db_bytes = bytes(df_string, 'utf8')
    dbx.files_upload(
        f=db_bytes,
        path=path,
        mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite
    )
    
token = "xxx"
p = today.replace("-",".")+".csv"
path = r"/Integrations/Customer for Life/UploadedFile" + p
df.head()    
to_dropbox(upload, path, token)
```

Here is the response:

```
FileMetadata(client_modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 26, 23, 44, 18), content_hash='xxx', export_info=NOT_SET, 
file_lock_info=NOT_SET, 
has_explicit_shared_members=NOT_SET, 
id='id:xxx', is_downloadable=True, 
media_info=NOT_SET, 
name='UploadedFile2021.10.26.csv', 
parent_shared_folder_id='xxx', 
path_display='/Integrations/Customer for Life/UploadedFile2021.10.26.csv', path_lower='/integrations/customer for life/uploadedfile2021.10.26.csv', 
property_groups=NOT_SET, 
rev='xxx', 
server_modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 26, 23, 44, 18), sharing_info=FileSharingInfo(modified_by='dbid:Axxx', 
parent_shared_folder_id='xxx', read_only=False), 
size=8868, 
symlink_info=NOT_SET)
```

UPDATE: It seems like there may be some disfunction with the API. It randomly started working again with no modification while producing identical responses. I will be investigating further and will send an update if I figure out the cause.

Comment: What is `df` and `upload`?

Comment: Sorry those are dataframes.

Comment: Does `dbx.files_upload` maybe throw any exceptions or return anything itself that you're ignoring?

Comment: Also, what's the expected behavior if there already is a file at the path you're trying to upload to?

Comment: Nope no exceptions. It returns the FileMetaData specified above.

Comment: The expected behavior is just to upload a new an additional file to the path, which is what the code was successfully doing for a while.